How to verify if a member has permission to do a Slash Command
I made a clear slash command, but the bot didn't verify the permissions of the interaction.user.
I tried with that @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True), but It's not working since it was working with a classic prefix command.
Also, I made error messages:
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(interaction, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
- await interaction.send("Unknown Member!")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await interaction.send("You do not have right permissions !", delete_after = 3)

And here is my clear command code:
@bot.tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=1264715762199691446), name="clear", description="Supprimer un certain nombre de messages.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
@app_commands.describe(nombre="Le nombre de messages à supprimer.")
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, nombre : int):
    messages = [message async for message in interaction.channel.history(limit = nombre)]
    for message in messages:
        await message.delete()
        

    return await interaction.response.send_message(f"**<:trash:1264750959372927057> __{nombre}__ message(s) supprimé(s).**", delete_after=3)

I actually want that my bot detect a missing permission with Slash Commands, and throw an error message to the user as seen above.
Also, as the member does have the right permissions, I want the bot to return nothing.

If you setup the command permissions in the discord server through 'Server Settings > Integrations', uesrs won't be able to run the command without the required permissions.

Same thing but a different decorator, rather than using the commands.has_permissions use app_commands.checks.has_permissions:
from discord import app_commands


@bot.tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=1264715762199691446), name="clear", description="Supprimer un certain nombre de messages.")
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@app_commands.describe(nombre="Le nombre de messages à supprimer.")
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, nombre : int):
    messages = [message async for message in interaction.channel.history(limit = nombre)]
    for message in messages:
        await message.delete()
        
    return await interaction.response.send_message(f"**<:trash:1264750959372927057> __{nombre}__ message(s) supprimé(s).**", delete_after=3)

PS: Remember that fetching messages is pretty slow (it will likely take more than 3 seconds) so you will have to use interaction.response.defer to have a longer time to respond and use interaction.followup.send to respond.
Reference: app_commands.checks.has_permissions
